# Merge a lot of data frames in R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, text-files

I have data on a all of the votes in the Danish Parliament in 2008-9. The problem is that each vote is recorded in its own .txt file with the following format (see the appendix of the post for a dump of three votes from R):

```
Name             Party  Vote
Anders Samuelsen LA     For
Rasmus Prehn     S      Imod
...              ...    ...
```

I would like to merge all the file to one data frame with the following format:

```
Name             Party  Vote1  Vote2  Vote3
Anders Samuelsen LA     For    Imod   Imod
Rasmus Prehn     S      Imod   For    FravÃ¦rende
```

(Danish translation:For = yes, imod = no, FravÃ¦rende = absent)

In total I have more than 200 files, so the question is: how can I write a loop that merges all the data frames into the desired structure above?

Appendix:

Vote1:

```
    structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 39L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 
65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 
75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 
88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 95L, 99L, 100L, 
101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 
112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 
123L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 124L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 
134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 138L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 
145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 
160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 165L, 166L, 
167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 
178L, 179L, 1L), .Label = c("Ã–zlem Sara Cekic", "Anders Samuelsen", 
"Anita Christensen", "Anita Knakkergaard", "Anne-Marie Meldgaard", 
"Anne-Mette Winther Christians", "Anne Baastrup", "Anne Grete Holmsgaard", 
"Annette Lilja Vilhelmsen", "Benny Engelbrecht", "Bent BÃ¸gsted", 
"Bente Dahl", "Bertel Haarder", "Birgitte Josefsen", "Birthe RÃ¸nn Hornbech", 
"Bjarne Laustsen", "Brian Mikkelsen", "Britta Schall Holberg", 
"Carina Christensen", "Carsten Hansen", "Charlotte Dyremose", 
"Christine Antorini", "Claus Hjort Frederiksen", "Colette L. Brix", 
"Connie Hedegaard", "Dennis FlydtkjÃ¦r", "Edmund Joensen", "Eigil Andersen", 
"Ellen Trane NÃ¸rby", "Erling Bonnesen", "Eva Kjer Hansen", "Eyvind Vesselbo", 
"Flemming Bonne", "Flemming Damgaard Larsen", "Flemming MÃ¸ller", 
"Flemming MÃ¸ller Mortensen", "Frank Aaen", "Gitte Lillelund Bech", 
"HÃ¸gni Hoydal", "Hanne Agersnap", "Hans Christian Schmidt", 
"Hans Christian Thoning", "Hans Kristian Skibby", "Helge Adam MÃ¸ller", 
"Helge Sander", "Helle Sjelle", "Helle Thorning-Schmidt", "Henriette KjÃ¦r", 
"Henrik Brodersen", "Henrik Dam Kristensen", "Henrik HÃ¸egh", 
"Henrik Sass Larsen", "Holger K. Nielsen", "Ib Poulsen", "Ida Auken", 
"Inger StÃ¸jberg", "JÃ¸rgen Poulsen", "JÃ¸rgen S. Lundsgaard", 
"JÃ¸rn Dohrmann", "Jacob Jensen", "Jakob Axel Nielsen", "Jens Christian Lund", 
"Jens Kirk", "Jens Peter Vernersen", "Jens Vibjerg", "Jeppe Kofod", 
"Jesper Langballe", "Jesper Petersen", "Johanne Schmidt-Nielsen", 
"John Dyrby Paulsen", "Johs. Poulsen", "Jonas Dahl", "Juliane Henningsen", 
"Julie Rademacher", "Kamal Qureshi", "Karen Ellemann", "Karen HÃ¦kkerup", 
"Karen J. Klint", "Karen Jespersen", "Karin NÃ¸dgaard", "Karina Lorentzen Dehnhardt", 
"Karl H. BornhÃ¸ft", "Karsten Lauritzen", "Karsten Nonbo", "Kim Andersen", 
"Kim Christiansen", "Kim Mortensen", "Kirsten BrosbÃ¸l", "Klaus HÃ¦kkerup", 
"Knud Kristensen", "Kristen Touborg", "Kristian Jensen", "Kristian Pihl Lorentzen", 
"Kristian Thulesen Dahl", "Lars-Emil Johansen", "Lars Barfoed", 
"Lars Christian Lilleholt", "Lars LÃ¸kke Rasmussen", "Leif Lahn Jensen", 
"Lene Espersen", "Lene Hansen", "Lennart Damsbo-Andersen", "Line Barfod", 
"Lise von Seelen", "Liselott Blixt", "Lone DybkjÃ¦r", "Lone MÃ¸ller", 
"Louise Schack Elholm", "Magnus Heunicke", "Malou Aamund", "Margrethe Vestager", 
"Marianne Jelved", "Marion Pedersen", "Marlene HarpsÃ¸e", "Martin Henriksen", 
"Meta Fuglsang", "Mette Frederiksen", "Mette Gjerskov", "Michael Aastrup Jensen", 
"Mike Legarth", "Mikkel Dencker", "Mogens Jensen", "Mogens Lykketoft", 
"Morten Ã˜stergaard", "Morten BÃ¸dskov", "Morten Helveg Petersen", 
"Morten Messerschmidt", "Nanna Westerby", "Naser Khader", "Nick HÃ¦kkerup", 
"Niels Christian Nielsen", "Niels Helveg Petersen", "Niels Sindal", 
"Ole HÃ¦kkerup", "Ole Sohn", "Ole Vagn Christensen", "Orla Hav", 
"Per Ã˜rum JÃ¸rgensen", "Per Bisgaard", "Per Clausen", "Per Stig MÃ¸ller", 
"Pernille Frahm", "Pernille VigsÃ¸ Bagge", "Peter Christensen", 
"Peter Juel Jensen", "Peter Skaarup", "Pia Adelsteen", "Pia Christmas-MÃ¸ller", 
"Pia KjÃ¦rsgaard", "Pia Olsen Dyhr", "Poul Andersen", "Preben Rudiengaard", 
"Rasmus Prehn", "RenÃ© Christensen", "RenÃ© Skau BjÃ¶rnsson", 
"SÃ¸ren Espersen", "SÃ¸ren Gade", "SÃ¸ren Krarup", "SÃ¸ren Pind", 
"Simon Emil AmmitzbÃ¸ll", "Sophie HÃ¦storp Andersen", "Sophie LÃ¸hde", 
"Steen Gade", "Svend Auken", "Thomas Adelskov", "Thomas Jensen", 
"Thor Pedersen", "Tina Nedergaard", "Tina Petersen", "Tom Behnke", 
"Torben Hansen", "Torsten Schack Pedersen", "Troels Christensen", 
"Troels Lund Poulsen", "Ulla TÃ¸rnÃ¦s", "Villum Christensen", 
"Villy SÃ¸vndal", "Vivi Kier", "Yildiz Akdogan"), class = "factor"), 
    V2 = structure(c(5L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 13L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 
    6L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 7L, 4L, 13L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 13L, 1L, 
    4L, 1L, 10L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 7L, 2L, 
    13L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 1L, 4L, 13L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 13L, 
    7L, 8L, 11L, 1L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 4L, 7L, 13L, 7L, 13L, 7L, 
    1L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 13L, 7L, 
    7L, 13L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 
    13L, 13L, 1L, 4L, 13L, 13L, 9L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 
    6L, 7L, 13L, 7L, 13L, 6L, 6L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 13L, 
    4L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
    8L, 7L, 7L, 13L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 
    1L, 8L, 7L, 13L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 12L, 7L, 13L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 13L, 
    1L, 13L, 7L, 7L, 13L, 13L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
    5L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("DF", "EL", "IA", "KF", "LA", 
    "RV", "S", "SF", "SIU", "SP", "TF", "UFG", "V"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("For", "FravÃ¦rende", "Imod"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -179L))
```

Vote2:

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 40L, 55L, 56L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 
64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 57L, 58L, 74L, 
75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 
88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 94L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 
101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 
112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 
124L, 125L, 126L, 123L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 
134L, 135L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 136L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 
145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 159L, 
160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 
167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 
178L, 179L, 1L), .Label = c("Ã–zlem Sara Cekic", "Anders Samuelsen", 
"Anita Christensen", "Anita Knakkergaard", "Anne-Marie Meldgaard", 
"Anne-Mette Winther Christians", "Anne Baastrup", "Anne Grete Holmsgaard", 
"Annette Lilja Vilhelmsen", "Bendt Bendtsen", "Benny Engelbrecht", 
"Bent BÃ¸gsted", "Bente Dahl", "Bertel Haarder", "Birgitte Josefsen", 
"Birthe RÃ¸nn Hornbech", "Bjarne Laustsen", "Brian Mikkelsen", 
"Britta Schall Holberg", "Carina Christensen", "Carsten Hansen", 
"Charlotte Dyremose", "Christine Antorini", "Claus Hjort Frederiksen", 
"Colette L. Brix", "Connie Hedegaard", "Dennis FlydtkjÃ¦r", "Edmund Joensen", 
"Eigil Andersen", "Ellen Trane NÃ¸rby", "Erling Bonnesen", "Eva Kjer Hansen", 
"Eyvind Vesselbo", "Flemming Bonne", "Flemming Damgaard Larsen", 
"Flemming MÃ¸ller", "Flemming MÃ¸ller Mortensen", "Frank Aaen", 
"Gitte Lillelund Bech", "HÃ¸gni Hoydal", "Hanne Agersnap", "Hans Christian Schmidt", 
"Hans Christian Thoning", "Hans Kristian Skibby", "Helge Adam MÃ¸ller", 
"Helge Sander", "Helle Sjelle", "Helle Thorning-Schmidt", "Henriette KjÃ¦r", 
"Henrik Brodersen", "Henrik Dam Kristensen", "Henrik HÃ¸egh", 
"Henrik Sass Larsen", "Holger K. Nielsen", "Ib Poulsen", "Inger StÃ¸jberg", 
"JÃ¸rgen Poulsen", "JÃ¸rn Dohrmann", "Jacob Jensen", "Jakob Axel Nielsen", 
"Jens Christian Lund", "Jens Kirk", "Jens Peter Vernersen", "Jens Vibjerg", 
"Jeppe Kofod", "Jesper Langballe", "Jesper Petersen", "Johanne Schmidt-Nielsen", 
"John Dyrby Paulsen", "Johs. Poulsen", "Jonas Dahl", "Juliane Henningsen", 
"Julie Rademacher", "Kamal Qureshi", "Karen Ellemann", "Karen HÃ¦kkerup", 
"Karen J. Klint", "Karen Jespersen", "Karin NÃ¸dgaard", "Karina Lorentzen Dehnhardt", 
"Karl H. BornhÃ¸ft", "Karsten Lauritzen", "Karsten Nonbo", "Kim Andersen", 
"Kim Christiansen", "Kim Mortensen", "Kirsten BrosbÃ¸l", "Klaus HÃ¦kkerup", 
"Knud Kristensen", "Kristen Touborg", "Kristian Jensen", "Kristian Pihl Lorentzen", 
"Kristian Thulesen Dahl", "Lars-Emil Johansen", "Lars Barfoed", 
"Lars Christian Lilleholt", "Lars LÃ¸kke Rasmussen", "Leif Lahn Jensen", 
"Lene Espersen", "Lene Hansen", "Lennart Damsbo-Andersen", "Line Barfod", 
"Lise von Seelen", "Liselott Blixt", "Lone DybkjÃ¦r", "Lone MÃ¸ller", 
"Louise Schack Elholm", "Magnus Heunicke", "Malou Aamund", "Margrethe Vestager", 
"Marianne Jelved", "Marion Pedersen", "Marlene HarpsÃ¸e", "Martin Henriksen", 
"Meta Fuglsang", "Mette Frederiksen", "Mette Gjerskov", "Michael Aastrup Jensen", 
"Mike Legarth", "Mikkel Dencker", "Mogens Jensen", "Mogens Lykketoft", 
"Morten Ã˜stergaard", "Morten BÃ¸dskov", "Morten Helveg Petersen", 
"Morten Messerschmidt", "Nanna Westerby", "Naser Khader", "Nick HÃ¦kkerup", 
"Niels Christian Nielsen", "Niels Helveg Petersen", "Niels Sindal", 
"Ole HÃ¦kkerup", "Ole Sohn", "Ole Vagn Christensen", "Per Ã˜rum JÃ¸rgensen", 
"Per Bisgaard", "Per Clausen", "Per Husted", "Per Stig MÃ¸ller", 
"Pernille Frahm", "Pernille VigsÃ¸ Bagge", "Peter Christensen", 
"Peter Juel Jensen", "Peter Skaarup", "Pia Adelsteen", "Pia Christmas-MÃ¸ller", 
"Pia KjÃ¦rsgaard", "Pia Olsen Dyhr", "Poul Andersen", "Preben Rudiengaard", 
"Rasmus Prehn", "RenÃ© Christensen", "RenÃ© Skau BjÃ¶rnsson", 
"SÃ¸ren Espersen", "SÃ¸ren Gade", "SÃ¸ren Krarup", "SÃ¸ren Pind", 
"Simon Emil AmmitzbÃ¸ll", "Sophie HÃ¦storp Andersen", "Sophie LÃ¸hde", 
"Steen Gade", "Svend Auken", "Thomas Adelskov", "Thomas Jensen", 
"Thor Pedersen", "Tina Nedergaard", "Tina Petersen", "Tom Behnke", 
"Torben Hansen", "Torsten Schack Pedersen", "Trine Mach", "Troels Christensen", 
"Troels Lund Poulsen", "Ulla TÃ¸rnÃ¦s", "Villum Christensen", 
"Villy SÃ¸vndal", "Vivi Kier", "Yildiz Akdogan"), class = "factor"), 
    V2 = structure(c(5L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 13L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 
    1L, 6L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 7L, 4L, 13L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 13L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 10L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 7L, 
    2L, 13L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 1L, 4L, 13L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 13L, 
    7L, 8L, 11L, 1L, 13L, 13L, 4L, 7L, 13L, 7L, 13L, 7L, 1L, 
    8L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 13L, 7L, 7L, 13L, 
    1L, 8L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 
    1L, 4L, 13L, 13L, 9L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 
    13L, 7L, 13L, 6L, 6L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 13L, 4L, 1L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 
    13L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 8L, 
    7L, 13L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 12L, 7L, 13L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 13L, 
    7L, 7L, 13L, 13L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 13L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 5L, 
    8L, 4L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("DF", "EL", "IA", "KF", "LA", 
    "RV", "S", "SF", "SIU", "SP", "TF", "UFG", "V"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("For", "FravÃ¦rende", "Imod"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -179L))
```

Vote3:

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 40L, 55L, 56L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 
64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 57L, 58L, 74L, 
75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 
88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 94L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 
101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 
112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 
124L, 125L, 126L, 123L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 
134L, 135L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 136L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 
145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 159L, 
160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 
167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 
178L, 179L, 1L), .Label = c("Ã–zlem Sara Cekic", "Anders Samuelsen", 
"Anita Christensen", "Anita Knakkergaard", "Anne-Marie Meldgaard", 
"Anne-Mette Winther Christians", "Anne Baastrup", "Anne Grete Holmsgaard", 
"Annette Lilja Vilhelmsen", "Bendt Bendtsen", "Benny Engelbrecht", 
"Bent BÃ¸gsted", "Bente Dahl", "Bertel Haarder", "Birgitte Josefsen", 
"Birthe RÃ¸nn Hornbech", "Bjarne Laustsen", "Brian Mikkelsen", 
"Britta Schall Holberg", "Carina Christensen", "Carsten Hansen", 
"Charlotte Dyremose", "Christine Antorini", "Claus Hjort Frederiksen", 
"Colette L. Brix", "Connie Hedegaard", "Dennis FlydtkjÃ¦r", "Edmund Joensen", 
"Eigil Andersen", "Ellen Trane NÃ¸rby", "Erling Bonnesen", "Eva Kjer Hansen", 
"Eyvind Vesselbo", "Flemming Bonne", "Flemming Damgaard Larsen", 
"Flemming MÃ¸ller", "Flemming MÃ¸ller Mortensen", "Frank Aaen", 
"Gitte Lillelund Bech", "HÃ¸gni Hoydal", "Hanne Agersnap", "Hans Christian Schmidt", 
"Hans Christian Thoning", "Hans Kristian Skibby", "Helge Adam MÃ¸ller", 
"Helge Sander", "Helle Sjelle", "Helle Thorning-Schmidt", "Henriette KjÃ¦r", 
"Henrik Brodersen", "Henrik Dam Kristensen", "Henrik HÃ¸egh", 
"Henrik Sass Larsen", "Holger K. Nielsen", "Ib Poulsen", "Inger StÃ¸jberg", 
"JÃ¸rgen Poulsen", "JÃ¸rn Dohrmann", "Jacob Jensen", "Jakob Axel Nielsen", 
"Jens Christian Lund", "Jens Kirk", "Jens Peter Vernersen", "Jens Vibjerg", 
"Jeppe Kofod", "Jesper Langballe", "Jesper Petersen", "Johanne Schmidt-Nielsen", 
"John Dyrby Paulsen", "Johs. Poulsen", "Jonas Dahl", "Juliane Henningsen", 
"Julie Rademacher", "Kamal Qureshi", "Karen Ellemann", "Karen HÃ¦kkerup", 
"Karen J. Klint", "Karen Jespersen", "Karin NÃ¸dgaard", "Karina Lorentzen Dehnhardt", 
"Karl H. BornhÃ¸ft", "Karsten Lauritzen", "Karsten Nonbo", "Kim Andersen", 
"Kim Christiansen", "Kim Mortensen", "Kirsten BrosbÃ¸l", "Klaus HÃ¦kkerup", 
"Knud Kristensen", "Kristen Touborg", "Kristian Jensen", "Kristian Pihl Lorentzen", 
"Kristian Thulesen Dahl", "Lars-Emil Johansen", "Lars Barfoed", 
"Lars Christian Lilleholt", "Lars LÃ¸kke Rasmussen", "Leif Lahn Jensen", 
"Lene Espersen", "Lene Hansen", "Lennart Damsbo-Andersen", "Line Barfod", 
"Lise von Seelen", "Liselott Blixt", "Lone DybkjÃ¦r", "Lone MÃ¸ller", 
"Louise Schack Elholm", "Magnus Heunicke", "Malou Aamund", "Margrethe Vestager", 
"Marianne Jelved", "Marion Pedersen", "Marlene HarpsÃ¸e", "Martin Henriksen", 
"Meta Fuglsang", "Mette Frederiksen", "Mette Gjerskov", "Michael Aastrup Jensen", 
"Mike Legarth", "Mikkel Dencker", "Mogens Jensen", "Mogens Lykketoft", 
"Morten Ã˜stergaard", "Morten BÃ¸dskov", "Morten Helveg Petersen", 
"Morten Messerschmidt", "Nanna Westerby", "Naser Khader", "Nick HÃ¦kkerup", 
"Niels Christian Nielsen", "Niels Helveg Petersen", "Niels Sindal", 
"Ole HÃ¦kkerup", "Ole Sohn", "Ole Vagn Christensen", "Per Ã˜rum JÃ¸rgensen", 
"Per Bisgaard", "Per Clausen", "Per Husted", "Per Stig MÃ¸ller", 
"Pernille Frahm", "Pernille VigsÃ¸ Bagge", "Peter Christensen", 
"Peter Juel Jensen", "Peter Skaarup", "Pia Adelsteen", "Pia Christmas-MÃ¸ller", 
"Pia KjÃ¦rsgaard", "Pia Olsen Dyhr", "Poul Andersen", "Preben Rudiengaard", 
"Rasmus Prehn", "RenÃ© Christensen", "RenÃ© Skau BjÃ¶rnsson", 
"SÃ¸ren Espersen", "SÃ¸ren Gade", "SÃ¸ren Krarup", "SÃ¸ren Pind", 
"Simon Emil AmmitzbÃ¸ll", "Sophie HÃ¦storp Andersen", "Sophie LÃ¸hde", 
"Steen Gade", "Svend Auken", "Thomas Adelskov", "Thomas Jensen", 
"Thor Pedersen", "Tina Nedergaard", "Tina Petersen", "Tom Behnke", 
"Torben Hansen", "Torsten Schack Pedersen", "Trine Mach", "Troels Christensen", 
"Troels Lund Poulsen", "Ulla TÃ¸rnÃ¦s", "Villum Christensen", 
"Villy SÃ¸vndal", "Vivi Kier", "Yildiz Akdogan"), class = "factor"), 
    V2 = structure(c(5L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 13L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 
    1L, 6L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 7L, 4L, 13L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 13L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 10L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 7L, 
    2L, 13L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 1L, 4L, 13L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 13L, 
    7L, 8L, 11L, 1L, 13L, 13L, 4L, 7L, 13L, 7L, 13L, 7L, 1L, 
    8L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 13L, 7L, 7L, 13L, 
    1L, 8L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 
    1L, 4L, 13L, 13L, 9L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 
    13L, 7L, 13L, 6L, 6L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 13L, 4L, 1L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 
    13L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 8L, 
    7L, 13L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 12L, 7L, 13L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 13L, 
    7L, 7L, 13L, 13L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 13L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 5L, 
    8L, 4L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("DF", "EL", "IA", "KF", "LA", 
    "RV", "S", "SF", "SIU", "SP", "TF", "UFG", "V"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("For", "FravÃ¦rende", "Imod"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -179L))
```

Comment: Hello Fellow Dane, could you provide us with the nomenclature that the files themselves take?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here is a slightly different approach using plyr and reshape packages by hadley.

```
library(plyr);
library(reshape);

# function to read a single file

readFile = function(i){

    .file = paste("Vote", i, ".csv", sep = "");
    .vote = read.csv(.file);
     names(.vote) = c('name', 'party', 'vote');
    .vote$id = paste("Vote", i, sep = "");
     return(.vote);
}

nFiles = 200;

# read all data files and store as data frame
vote = ldply(1:nFiles, readFile);

# reshape data to get to the required format
vote2 = cast(vote, name + party ~ id, value = 'vote')
```

Answer (score 5):

This is how I handle multiple imports. I hope my example suits your needs.
What you do is you read all the filenames in the directory, import each file as a list element and `rbind` the whole list into one data.frame. I assume your files begin with `voting_results_*`.

```
# Create a list of files
import.files <- as.list(grep("voting_results_", list.files(), value = TRUE))

importResults <- function(x) {
    read.table(x, header = TRUE) # customize this to meet your needs
}

# Using lapply on each list element, import all files into one list.
voting.results <- lapply(import.files, FUN = importResults)

# R bind all list elements into one big data.frame.
voting.results <- do.call("rbind", voting.results)

# Dance.
```

Answer (score 4):

If you assume that Party is always the same, then just merge (twice) by the Names (== "V1" in your structures):

```
mergevotes <- merge(merge(Vote1, Vote2[, c(1,3)], by="V1"), Vote3[, c(1,3)], by="V1")
 names(mergevotes) <- c("Name", "Party",  "Vote1",  "Vote2",  "Vote3")
```

> str(mergevotes)
>   data.frame':    176 obs. of  5 variables:
>    $ Name : Factor w/ 179 levels "Ã–zlem Sara Cekic",..: 1 2 3 4 7 8 5 6 9 10 ...
>    $ Party: Factor w/ 13 levels "DF","EL","IA",..: 8 5 1 1 8 8 7 13 8 7 ...
>    $ Vote1: Factor w/ 3 levels "For","FravÃ¦rende",..: 2 1 1 1 3 3 2 1 3 3 ...
>    $ Vote2: Factor w/ 3 levels "For","FravÃ¦rende",..: 2 3 1 1 3 2 2 2 2 3 ...
>    $ Vote3: Factor w/ 3 levels "For","FravÃ¦rende",..: 2 3 3 3 2 2 1 2 2 1 ...
>   head(mergevotes)

```
                   Name Party       Vote1       Vote2       Vote3  
1     Ã–zlem Sara Cekic    SF FravÃ¦rende FravÃ¦rende FravÃ¦rende
2      Anders Samuelsen    LA         For        Imod        Imod
3     Anita Christensen    DF         For         For        Imod
4    Anita Knakkergaard    DF         For         For        Imod
5         Anne Baastrup    SF        Imod        Imod FravÃ¦rende
6 Anne Grete Holmsgaard    SF        Imod FravÃ¦rende FravÃ¦rende
```

I wish the SO Interface made it easy to specify non-proportional fonts such as Courier. It seems to be eating the spacing that R offers to line up tabular output when pasted into text sections.

Answer (score 3):

Adjust read.csv to whatever type of file it is that you're pulling in. This example assumes that the nomenclature of the files follows:

Vote1.csv
Vote2.csv
...
Vote200.csv

```
n <- 200 ## Number of votes
df <- read.csv(file=paste("Vote1.csv",sep=""))
df.tmp <- data.frame() ## initialize

for (x in 2:n) { 
df.tmp <- read.csv(file=paste("Vote",n,".csv",sep=""))
df <- merge(df,df.tmp[c(1,3)], by="V1")
} 

colnames(df)[3:n] <- paste("Vote",1:n,sep="")
colnames(df)[1:2] <- c("Name","Party")
```

Comment: growing objects: the R Inferno now counts you in its circles